# C#: Background waiting for pressing key

Tags: c#, console

I have a class with two dimensional array, where is function for moving elements from right to left. I have a problem with testing pressed key. I wrote something like this in Main, but I dont want to wait to press some key...I want that run "on background"...is there some way how to do it without using Thread?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PlayingArea game = new PlayingArea(16, 80);
        char pressedKey;

        while (true)
        {
            game.Update();  
            pressedKey = Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar;
            Console.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Here is my Update function:

```
    public void Update()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < playArray.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < playArray.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
               if(playArray[i,j].status != status.texture)
                {                    
                    playArray[i, j - 1] = playArray[i, j];                            
                }
            }
        }
        Print();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(80);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an old trick for doing so, that consist in checking the keyboard without blocking the program.
Unfortunately ( not a big deal anyway ) you need platform invoke, so on Windows platform you have to invoke the API [GetAsyncKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
In order to PInvoke this function you can use this code:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(System.Windows.Forms.Keys vKey);
```

With this code you can see if a key is pressed and more ( ie if AlT/Shift/ctrl are pressed too)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be scared of threading. Simple program that should fulfill your requirements:

```
class Program
{
    private ConsoleKeyInfo last_key;
    private void Update()
    {
        while(last_key.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Last pressed button: " + last_key.KeyChar);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
    private async Task MainProgram()
    {
        Task upd_task = Task.Run(new Action(Update));

        while(last_key.Key!=ConsoleKey.Escape)
            last_key = Console.ReadKey(true);

        await upd_task;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        p.MainProgram().Wait();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works pretty well for me

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char c = '.';
        while (true)
        {
            if (Console.KeyAvailable) // check KeyAvailable since ReadKey is a blocking call
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true); // true - will intercept the key and won't show it
                c = keyInfo.KeyChar;
            }
            Console.Write(c);
        }
    }
```